# How do I repeat / spread background image depending on number of divs on the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm aware of the css properties `background-size: cover;` and `background-size: contain;` however despite of description of its usage I can't seem get it to work the way I need.

At the moment I'm adjusting coverage of the background image manually which is very impractical as you can imagine. How can I adjust coverage or repetition based on how many divs are on a page ?
On the mobile viewport its particularly desired. When I scroll down on the phone I want to see all divs covered to the footer. If I add another div (think a comment) background image would be extended.

```
body {
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 1000px;  /* <-- impractical way of adjusting coverage */
  }
```

I'm considering a javascript solution but it wouldn't be elegant but rather cumbersome. Is there "built-in" solution to this ?

Comment: Why do you need to set the size of a background that is repeating anyway? Questions like this should come with a proper [mre] that illustrates the actual issue.

Answer (score -1):

All I needed to do is to replace lines:

```
background-size: contain;
height: 1000px;
```

with:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

works like a charm.

Comment: you said you are aware about `cover` so your answer doens't make a lot of sense plus we no more need to use prefixes with background-size